# gulp-base64 - stop on error

Tags: css, build, gulp

I use gulp as a build system in my web project

I have a number of CSS files (well, actually, LESS, but it does not matter)

I do link image files from my CSS rules in this way:

```
.my-rule {
    background-image: url('/images/kitten.svg');
}
```

Next, I'm embedding those images as Base-64 into my production CSS files.

That is a gulp task:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    ...
    base64 = require('gulp-base64');


gulp.task("sass", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
      .pipe(base64())
      .pipe(concat("concatedstyles.css"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + "css"));
});
```

The problem is:

When I link to non-existing file:

```
.my-rule {
    background-image: url('/images/non-existing-kitten.svg');
}
```

the build system does not report me about failure.
It just leave this line as is.

So, I'm not aware about error at build time, only at runtime.

I tried to play with `.pipe(sass.sync().on("error", sass.logError))`, but no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: You can use the `debug` option to generate a warning, but that's it. `gulp-base64` [silently ignores](https://github.com/Wenqer/gulp-base64/blob/d44929d/lib/encode.js#L236) missing files. Your only option is to open an issue on GitHub and ask the author to make that behavior configurable (or fork the plugin).

Comment: @SvenSchoenung thank you. Maybe you know some alternate gulp-solutions for base64 embedding?..